# bash script may need root permission

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, root

I'm trying to learn bash scripting. I wrote a script that converts spaces to underscores in filenames. It works okay. So far so good.

It is possible my script enters a certain directory, containing files that are owned by another user (e.g. root or www-data).

My script is not able to convert these files luckily :) But I prefer a warning message, like "You need root permissions" or so.

This the conversion block:

```
if  [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
    echo "Converting directory $2 .."
    find . -name '* *' | while read file
    do
        target=`echo "$file" | sed 's/ /_/g'`
        mv "$file" "$target" 2> /dev/null
    done
else
    fOptionE (produces usage message)
fi
```

Can you help me finding a proper way to return a "Needs root permission" output?

Comment: Remove the `2> /dev/null` to make `mv` write useful, canonical error messages. This is better than claiming that you need root, because there are many other reasons why mv could fail.

Comment: If you want to check for "needing root" you could try to manually check permissions but that's not necessarily a simple thing to do correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the execute permission to your script

```
chmod u+x your_script.sh
./your_script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the file is writable:

```
if [ ! -w "$file" ]
then
  echo "The file is NOT writable"
else
  echo "The file is writable"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [ x"`whoami`"x != x"root"x ]
then
    : # do something
fi
```